# handle kotlin coroutines withContext exceptions inside try-catch not work

Tags: android, kotlin, exception, kotlin-coroutines, moshi

I call network operations like this.

```
viewModelScope.launch {
try {
        val data = withContext(dispatcher.io()) { homeRepository.getData() }
    } catch (e: Throwable) {
        val error = globalErrorHandler.getMessageForUser(throwable)
                Timber.d("seriesResponse failed: $error")
    }
}
```

and the response model is

```
data class MainResponse<T>(
    val list: List<T> = emptyList(),
    val total: Int?
)
```

but it still throw the following error.

```
Fatal Exception: com.squareup.moshi.JsonDataException
Non-null value 'credits' was null at $.data[1].credits
```

What's wrong with my code? I think it should catch the error.

**UPDATED**
This is my mistake, this line `val error = globalErrorHandler.getMessageForUser(throwable)` cause the error, I forgot to handle it.

Comment: I believe it should catch the exception. Could you provide your `getData()` and a full stacktrace?

Comment: @broot I update the full stacktrace

Comment: @FrankMungNo implementation of getData would be useful also

Comment: The exception message looks like the error occurs after try-catch block. Is there any operations with `data` after that?

Comment: @Steyrix I updated the questions, this is totally my mistake that I forgot to handle some errors.

Comment: @FrankMungNo so you don't need an answer then? You can close the question by posting your own answer

Answer (score 0):

This is my mistake, this line `val error = globalErrorHandler.getMessageForUser(throwable)` cause the error, I forgot to handle it.